# Switch from one DataTemplate to other

Tags: c#, wpf, double-click, listboxitems, datatemplate

In my wpf application, there is View class where I've ListBox. I wrote the code for double click event of ListBox Item.so when I double click on any list Box Item that item will be posted in my Harvest account.Here is the event:

```
private void listBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //Submit clicked Entry
        try
        {
            ListBoxItem item = (ListBoxItem)sender;
            Harvest_TimeSheetEntry entryToPost = (Harvest_TimeSheetEntry)item.DataContext;

            if (!entryToPost.isSynced)
            {
                //Check if something is selected in selectedProjectItem For that item
                if (entryToPost.ProjectNameBinding == "Select Project" && entryToPost.ClientNameBinding == "Select Client")
                    MessageBox.Show("Please select you Project and Client");
                else
                    Globals._globalController.harvestManager.postHarvestEntry(entryToPost);
                    MessageBox.Show("Entry posted");
            }
            else
            {

                //Already synced.. Make a noise or something
                MessageBox.Show("Already Synced;TODO Play a Sound Instead");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }
     }
```

My xaml code:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultDataTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="596">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding ClientNameBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="145"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding ApplicationNameBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="90"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding StartTimeBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="100"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding StopTimeBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="60"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding ProjectNameBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="130"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding TaskNameBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="71"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <!-- Editable DataTemplate -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="EditableDataTemplate">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="596">
                <ComboBox x:Name="ClientComboBox" SelectionChanged="ProjectComboBoxChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=clientList, ElementName=MainWin}" SelectedValuePath="_id" DisplayMemberPath="_name" SelectedItem="{Binding ClientNameBindingClass, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" Width="145"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding ApplicationNameBinding}" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="90"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding StartTimeBinding}" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="100"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding StopTimeBinding}" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="60"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding TaskNameBinding}" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="130"/>
                <ComboBox x:Name="ProjectComboBox" SelectionChanged="ProjectComboBoxChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=projectList, ElementName=MainWin}" SelectedValuePath="_id" DisplayMemberPath="_name"  SelectedItem="{Binding ProjectNameBindingClass, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Width="71" Background="Yellow" BorderThickness="0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>




        <!-- DataTemplate Selector -->

        <l:DayViewListDataTemplateSelector x:Key="templateSelector"
          DefaultDataTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultDataTemplate}"
          EditableDataTemplate="{StaticResource EditableDataTemplate}"/>
```

I've timer in my class which generates that EditableDataTemplate with two comboBoxes. My problem is, when I select Client and Project in ComboBoxes and double click on the entry, it's posted in my account but at that time I want it to convert from editableDataTemplate to DefaultDataTemplate (i.e those two comboboxes should become textboxes likewise in DefaultDataTemplate). How should I achieve this result?

Comment: Have you checked DataTemplateSelector? [WPF Tutorial - How To Use A DataTemplateSelector](http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector)

Comment: @sll, you should probably write that in an answer.

Comment: Yes. I've checked. I just want to convert at that moment when I double click on that entry.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the DataTemplateSelector offers a method of changing the data template on request, it is merely used to choose different templates for different types of data (not data states).
I think probably the best way would be to add a property, lets call it IsInEditMode, to your data model. You could then add both the TextBlock and the Combobox to your data template and toggle their visibility according to the value of IsInEditMode.

By the way: if you use the ListBox.SelectedItem property in your DoubleClick-eventhandler you can directly access the data model element without having to first get the ListBoxItem and then access 
its data context.

```
private void listBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //Submit clicked Entry
    try
    {
        if(listBox1.SelectedItem is Harvest_TimeSheetEntry)
        {
            Harvest_TimeSheetEntry entryToPost = (Harvest_TimeSheetEntry)listBox1.SelectedItem;

            if (!entryToPost.isSynced)
            {
                //Check if something is selected in selectedProjectItem For that item
                if (entryToPost.ProjectNameBinding == "Select Project" && entryToPost.ClientNameBinding == "Select Client")
                    MessageBox.Show("Please select you Project and Client");
                else
                    Globals._globalController.harvestManager.postHarvestEntry(entryToPost);
                    MessageBox.Show("Entry posted");

                    entryToPost.IsInEditMode = true; //set edit mode!
            }
        }
        else
        {

            //Already synced.. Make a noise or something
            MessageBox.Show("Already Synced;TODO Play a Sound Instead");
        }

    }
    catch (Exception)
    { }
 }
```

Comment: I tried your method but, when I double click on listBox item, the entries are saved in that sender object. And we can't take listBox entries directly into any class object. That's working properly now. Problem is of switching of DataTemplates only.

Comment: Have you tried adding the extra property so you won't have to switch the template? Remember to use INotifyPropertyChanged or Dependency Properties to implement it, as otherwise changes to its value will not automatically be applied to the UI.